# Why my code doesn't work when the script tag is in the head tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I was making a webpage with a video.
and I wanted to change the size of the video depending on the size of the window.

the code below is my HTML code:

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" poster="images/video_poster.png" width="320" height="240">
      <source src="video/Minions.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="video/Minions.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

and my script code for that is below:

```
  <script>var video = document.getElementById("video");
    function changeVideoSize() {
      console.log("width is: ", window.innerWidth)
      if (window.innerWidth > 900) {
        video.width = "640";
        video.height = "480";
      }
      else {
        video.width = "320";
        video.height = "240";
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", changeVideoSize)
    function init() {
    }
    init();
  </script>
```

first, I place this script code at the end of the head tag, and it made an error "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'width')".

I was stuck with this error for an hour...
and then after many different tries,
I put it at the end of body tag, and it worked.

Why is it?
What are the main differences between putting it in head and body??
Should I always put the script tag at the end of the body tag?
or it depends on the cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `HTML` get parsed from `top to bottom`, So Whatever encounter first will get run.

If you put `script` tag at the end of the `head` tag then It will run first before the HTML `body` so you can't set `width` because when you used

```
document.getElementById("video")
```

It would return `null` so you can't set properties on `null`. Because at the time of this statement the element doesn't exist.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    const heading = document.querySelector("h1");
    console.log(heading); // null
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> This is heading</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

So you have to put the `script` tag at the end of the `body` tag. So that the when JS get parsed and gets executed then It can find the `HTML` element and executes the statements.

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> This is heading</h1>
  
    <script>
    const heading = document.querySelector("h1");
    console.log(heading); // h1 element
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the pure sequence. The interpreter reads from top to bottom in this case. and if your code in the head says get me element X and it is not yet in the DOM, then that is null. It's different in the footer, where element x is already loaded in the DOM, and that's why the script works. JS in most cases always just before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

basically when you are putting it in your head tag , then script is parsing before body tag. so there is no video tag inside document with id video.
Use external script with defer attribute or put script below your html code inside the  tag.
Sorry for my bad english.